# Onvif Simulator For Testing Onvif web service client

Tags: camera, simulator, onvif

Hi i am trying to develop an android web service client consuming onvif web service , but I do not have any onvif camera in my hand. What I need is an onvif camera simulator , test tool ,(may be link of an onvif camera to try basic operations like getdeviceinformation if possible ) which is free . I googled it but I could not find any . Is there any this kind of things ?

Comment: The HappyTimeSoft emulator now costs nearly $300. Must've been pretty successful freeware back in the day.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very good, free one : http://www.happytimesoft.com/products/multi-onvif-server/index.html