# IP-camera/light sensor Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, camera, ip-camera, onvif

I have a Node.js server application which I would like to connect several IP-cameras to. I found out about the ONVIF IP-camera standard, but I find it hard to find cheap (less than 50€) ONVIF IP-cameras from Europe.

Is there any other way of accessing IP-camera data from a Node.js server other than through ONVIF standard? Basically I want to either trigger node.js function on motion detection or if the cameras/light sensors light value changes.

ONVIF node.js implementation: https://github.com/agsh/onvif 
ONVIF IP-camera support list: http://www.onvif.org/ConformantProducts/ProfileProducts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have introduced an ONVIF Emulator in the following post:
[Onvif Simulator For Testing Onvif web service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562584/onvif-simulator-for-testing-onvif-web-service-client/40122428#40122428)

You can also search for demo cameras that manufacturers allow you to access the device for test. For instance:
https://www.toshibasecurity.com/products/Live-Demo-Cameras/